Laptop won't shut down sometimes
My Lenovo Yoga 510-14IKB running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS won't shut down every time when I select the option through Gnome's panel dropdown (or through the small popup by pressing the physical power button). Most of the time it does shut down, but once in a while it turns the screen black and leaves it on and lit. It displays a flashing underscore in the top left corner for a minute or two, and then shows this (or something similar, not sure since I wrote it down only this time):
[ 3195.457471] wlp3s0: deauthenticating from 28:41:c6:21:0b:10 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Once I left it like that and it stayed on for over half an hour until the battery was completely drained. When this happens, my only option is to force the shutdown by holding the button for 5s. It's annoying to have to stare at the screen every time I wanna shut down just to see if it will actually shut down. If I close the laptop it stays on until it drains the battery.
What can I do to try to fix this?

A quick tap of the power button puts many laptops into sleep mode. You describe such a situation in your question. NEVER use the power button to shutdown the computer unless it is froze and you have no other choice you may damage the OS. Shutting the laptop also in most models is not a shut down but puts it in sleep mode. I do not see that you actually have an OS problem. I feel that you actually do not have anything to fix.

@DavidDE As I said in my post, a quick tap of the power button opens the popup titled "Power Off" with a 60s countdown and "Cancel" and "Power Off" options. That's the same popup that we can reach from top panel, far right, "Power Off / Log Out", "Power Off...". Closing the laptop should put it to sleep but that's not what I want to do. My problem is indeed in the power off process.
